# How can i send context in this object?

Tags: javascript, call, bind, apply

For example i have simple code:

```
let arrayOfObjects = [{
  arrays: [arraysFunction("array object 1", "some url", () => {
    console.log(this);  // it should return {name: "array object 1", url: "some url", callback: fn}
  }])
}];


function arraysFunction(name, url, callback) {
  return {name, url, callback}
}
```

I would be want to have here my array object in this
how can i make it with (apply, call, bind) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use all/apply just use the following

```
let object = {
  arrays: [arraysFunction("array object 1", "some url", function(){
    console.log(this);
  })]
};


function arraysFunction(name, url, callback) {
  return callback.apply({name, url, callback});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let object = {
  arrays: [arraysFunction("array object 1", "some url", function() {
    console.log(this);  // it should return {name: "array object 1", url: "some url", callback: fn}
  }]
};

function arraysFunction(name, url, callback) {
  callback = callback.bind({name, url, callback});
  return {name, url, callback};
}
```

the only problem is that callback that is returned will not be the same as the one in this (`===` will not work).